# Eloquent Collection: Counting and Detect Empty

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, eloquent, laravel-collection

This may be a trivial question but I am wondering if Laravel recommends a certain way to check whether an Eloquent collection returned from `$result = Model::where(...)->get()` is empty, as well as counting the number of elements.

We are currently using `!$result` to detect empty result, is that sufficient? As for `count($result)`, does it actually cover all cases, including empty result?

Answer (score 733, accepted):

When using `->get()` you cannot simply use any of the below:

```
if (empty($result)) { }
if (!$result) { }
if ($result) { }
```

Because if you `dd($result);` you'll notice an instance of `Illuminate\Support\Collection` is always returned, even when there are no results. Essentially what you're checking is `$a = new stdClass; if ($a) { ... }` which will always return true.

To determine if there are any results you can do any of the following:

```
if ($result->first()) { } 
if (!$result->isEmpty()) { }
if ($result->count()) { }
if (count($result)) { }
```

You could also use `->first()` instead of `->get()` on the query builder which will return an instance of the first found model, or `null` otherwise. This is useful if you need or are expecting only one result from the database.

```
$result = Model::where(...)->first();
if ($result) { ... }
```

**Notes / References**

- **`->first()`** http://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Collection.html#method_first
- **`isEmpty()`** http://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Collection.html#method_isEmpty
- **`->count()`** http://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Collection.html#method_count
- **`count($result)`** works because the Collection implements [Countable](http://php.net/manual/en/class.countable.php) and an internal `count()` method: http://laravel.com/api/4.2/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Collection.html#method_count

## Bonus Information

The Collection and the Query Builder differences can be a bit confusing to newcomers of Laravel because the method names are often the same between the two. For that reason it can be confusing to know what one you’re working on. The Query Builder essentially builds a query until you call a method where it will execute the query and hit the database (e.g. when you call certain methods like `->all()` `->first()` `->lists()` and others). Those methods *also* exist on the `Collection` object, which can get returned from the Query Builder if there are multiple results. If you're not sure what class you're actually working with, try doing `var_dump(User::all())` and experimenting to see what classes it's actually returning (with help of `get_class(...)`). I highly recommend you check out the source code for the Collection class, it's pretty simple. Then check out the Query Builder and see the similarities in function names and find out when it actually hits the database.

- [Laravel 5.2 Collection Class](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Support/Collection.php)
- [Laravel 5.2 Query Builder](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.2/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php)

Comment: thx, just to add that if you run query `first()`, the result is different from `get()`, which can be checked with `!$result` as empty result is `null`

Comment: @btinn yes -- if you did i.e. `Model::first()` -- it's actually acting on the 'first` method of the query builder and NOT the collection, therefore it will pick the first one from the database -- however `Model::get()` will return an instance of Illuminate\Support\Collection so if you did `$r = Model::get()` and then `$r->first()` it will pick out the first item within that collection.

Comment: One thing this answer doesn't address is whether `count($result)` works; adding that detail would be an improvement.

Comment: what's the difference between $result->count and count($result)
Does $result->count hit the database again? If not, I guess these are the same then!

Comment: $result->count doesnt hit the database again as it uses the collection Facade helper function count()

Comment: !$result->isEmpty() isn't working for me in Laravel 5.2.

Comment: How about when you only one want to check whether a specific column (property) like in `$collection->column` is empty / null or not?

Comment: @pathros There's no simple way of doing that. You would have to iterate through each member of the collection using a `foreach` loop and then use one of these checks (think: `count($collection->column)`).

Comment: great to know that first returns null if no record is found!

Comment: Doesn't work for me, at least not on an empty collection.

Answer (score 100):

I think you are looking for:

```
$result->isEmpty()
```

This is different from `empty($result)`, which will not be true because the result will be an empty collection. Your suggestion of `count($result)` is also a good solution. I cannot find any reference in the docs

Comment: How about when you only one want to check whether a specific column (property) like in $collection->column is empty / null or not?

Answer (score 20):

I agree the above approved answer. But usually I use `$results->isNotEmpty()` method as given below.

```
if($results->isNotEmpty())
{
//do something
}
```

It's more verbose than `if(!results->isEmpty())` because sometimes we forget to add '!'  in front which may result in unwanted error.

Note that this method exists from version [5.3](https://laravel.com/api/5.3/Illuminate/Support/Collection.html#method_isNotEmpty) onwards.

Answer (score 17):

There are several methods given in Laravel for checking results count/check empty/not empty:

```
$result->isNotEmpty(); // True if result is not empty.
$result->isEmpty(); // True if result is empty.
$result->count(); // Return count of records in result.
```

Answer (score 11):

According to Laravel [Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-isempty) states you can use this way:

```
$result->isEmpty();
```

The `isEmpty` method returns `true` if the collection is empty; otherwise, `false` is returned.

Answer (score 9):

I think better to used

```
$result->isEmpty();
```

> The isEmpty method returns true if the collection is empty; otherwise,
>   false is returned.

Answer (score 7):

I think you try something like

```
  @if(!$result->isEmpty())
         // $result is not empty
    @else
        // $result is empty
    @endif
```

or also use

```
if (!$result) { }
if ($result) { }
```

Answer (score 5):

You can do

```
$result = Model::where(...)->count();
```

to count the results.

You can also use

```
if ($result->isEmpty()){}
```

to check whether or not the result is empty.

Answer (score 1):

so Laravel actually returns a collection when just using `Model::all();`
you don't want a collection you want an array so you can type set it.
`(array)Model::all();` then you can use array_filter to return the results

```
$models = (array)Model::all()
$models = array_filter($models);
if(empty($models))
{
 do something
}
```

this will also allow you to do things like `count()`.

Comment: keeping it as a collection is actually convenient so that the objects returned can still inherit lots of useful function in the collection facade.

Answer (score 1):

**You can use:** `$counter = count($datas);`

Answer (score 1):

now you can use

```
$query = Model::where(...);
$isExists = $query->exists();
$count = $query->count();
```

https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queries#determining-if-records-exist
https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queries#aggregates

Answer (score 0):

You want to check these two cases of `count()`.

**#1**

If the result contains only a single row (one record) from the database by using `->first()`.

```
if(count($result)) {
    // record is exist true...
}
```

**#2**

If result contain set of multiple row (multiple records) by using `->get()` or `->all()`.

```
if($result->count()) {
    //record is exist true...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The [`in_array()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) checks if a value exists in an array.

```
public function isAbsolutelyEmpty($value)
{
   return in_array($value, ["", "0", null, 0, 0.0], true);
}
```