# How to check object of a model is empty in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5

I am accessing my database using model by using following code.

```
$persons = WysPerson::where('family_id', $id)->get();
```

I checked `$persons`is empty or not by using following code.

```
if($persons){
        var_dump($persons);
    }
```

Actually `$persons` is empty. But I am getting result for `var_dump` as

`object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection)#417 (1) { ["items":protected]=> array(0) { } }`

How will I check `$persons` is empty? Can anyone help?

Comment: @Naruto collections are not arrays. isEmpty is the right method as answered below by Angel

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Eloquent collection: counting and detect empty](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563166/eloquent-collection-counting-and-detect-empty)

Comment: The title is misleading. "Object of a model is empty" implies whether an instance of `\Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model` has no attributes set (which is why I'm in here). You're really asking whether the collection returned by a `get` operation on a model is empty.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can use the isEmpty method:

http://laravel.com/api/5.0/Illuminate/Support/Collection.html#method_isEmpty

Comment: I tried to use isEmpty like "var_dump(isEmpty($persons));" .. but I am getting error "Call to undefined function isEmpty()"?

Comment: Its a method of the collection, you should be calling $persons->isEmpty();

Answer (score 4):

If you have eloquent collection, call the function `isEmpty()` like this:

```
$persons->isEmpty();
```

This return true or false.
Hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Use the count function

@if (count($persons))

Comment: there is an issue with your answer, if you forgot to execute the query with ->get() and just leave the query in place count will return 1. isEmpty will throw an exception which in the grand scheme of things is better.

Comment: And checking collection count wont work, till it's Laravel collection

Answer (score 1):

try this.

```
is_null($var)?abort('empty'):abort('filled')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use isEmpty() method.

At the same time you can check it by simply with count() method before once you fetch the data.

```
    $count = WysPerson::where('family_id', $id)->count();
    if($count==0){
       return redirect()->back()->withErrors('Empty Data');
     }
    $persons = WysPerson::where('family_id', $id)->get();
```