# variable showing null value in view laravel

Tags: laravel

i am trying to sent data to view from function in controller but the variable view is not showing any result

```
public function goedit($id)
{
    $catg = Category::where('cat_id',$id)->first();
    return view('product.gocatedit')->with('row', $catg);
}
```

and my view is

```
 @if(isset($row))

                <form action="{{action('ProductController@edit')}}" method="post">
                  <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
                  <div class="col-sm-12">
                    <h1 style="text-align:center;">Edit Items</h1>
                    <table  class="table">
                            <thead>
                            <tr>
                              <th>ID</th>
                              <th>Category</th>
                              <th>Item</th>
                              <th>Price</th>
                              <th></th>
                            </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                            <tr>
                              <input type="hidden" name="item_id" value="{{ $row->item_id}}">
                              <td><input class="form-control" name="item_name" value="{{$row->item_name}}" /></td>
                              <td><input class="form-control" name="item_price" value="{{$row->item_price}}" /></td>
                              <td><input class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat" type="submit" value="Edit"></td>
                            </tr>
                            </tbody>

                    </table>
                    </div>
                </form>
            @endif
```

please help thanks

Comment: Please, read this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563166/eloquent-collection-counting-and-detect-empty/20585483#20585483). It should help you.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you query returning `null`, that's the problem (there is no such ID in a database).

If you want to check for `null`, use `is_null`:

```
@if(is_null($var))
```

Or maybe you want to use `empty`:

```
@if(!empty($row))
```

Comment: no its not null bcoz if i var_dump($row) at function it is showing the result.

Comment: Could you post result of `dd($row);` please?

Comment: item {#228 ▼
  #fillable: array:4 [▶]
  #primaryKey: "item_id"
  #connection: null
  #table: null
  #perPage: 15
  +incrementing: true
  +timestamps: true
  #attributes: array:6 [▼
    "item_id" => "1"
    "item_name" => "Chinese Noodls"
    "item_price" => "123"
    "cat_name" => "Chinese"
    "created_at" => "2016-04-09 11:02:15"
    "updated_at" => "2016-04-14 06:37:54"
  ]
  #original: array:6 [▶]
  #relations: []
  #hidden: []
  #visible: []
  #appends: []
  #guarded: array:1 [▶]
  #observables: []
  #with: []
  #morphClass: null
  +exists: true
  +wasRecentlyCreated: false
}

Comment: Did you run `dd()` in a view? If `$row` has right data, what variable is `null` then?

Comment: actually i am trying to send variable to the view from which i have called the function, and trying to show it on the modal.

Comment: So, in a view everthing is fine and you do not get the var in `ProductController@edit` method? If yes, use `{{ action('ProductController@edit', ['row' => $row] ) }}` to pass variable into `edit`.

Comment: ProductController@edit is to update into DB. it is working fine if i use different view to show data to be edit, but now i am trying to retrieve the data at same view to show that on Modal (bootstrap modal) but unfortunately m not able to receive the variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function goedit($id)
{
    $catg = Category::where('cat_id',$id)->first();
    return view('product.gocatedit')->with('row', $catg);
}
```

practically should be:

```
public function goedit($id)
{
    $catg = Category::findOrFail($id);
    return view('product.gocatedit')->with('row', $catg);
}
```

and then it seems that you aren't using default primary key, which is "id", so in your model add

```
public class Category{

           ...................

          protected $primaryKey = "cat_id";
          .....................

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use `->with('something', 'data')`, then the data passed will be in the `session('something')` and it's purpose is to 'flash' messages.

You need this (view data is supposed to be passed as an array, and as a second parameter of the `view()` function):

```
public function goedit($id)
{
    $catg = Category::where('cat_id',$id)->first();
    return view('product.gocatedit', ['row' => $catg]);
}
```