# hidden title if data empty in blade laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I want to hide the title if there is no data show in foreach result. so, where should i place the section title?

this is the code

```
<div class="title">
//section title
   <div class="navigation-bar">
        <h3>Title</h3>
    </div>

 @foreach($similar_posts as $related_post)
  //data
 @endforeach

</div>
```

thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Eloquent collection: counting and detect empty](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563166/eloquent-collection-counting-and-detect-empty)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<div class="title">

  @if( ! $similar_posts->isEmpty() )

    //section title
    <div class="navigation-bar">
        <h3>Title</h3>
    </div>

    @foreach($similar_posts as $related_post)
      //data
    @endforeach

  @endif

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always check if your collection is (not) empty and only output the title if it contains something:

```
@if(!$similar_posts->isEmpty())
    {{ $title }}
@endif
```

Keep in mind tho that there are several ways to check if something is empty, refer to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563166/eloquent-collection-counting-and-detect-empty) to find out which one suits you the best.