# Get an array from an object | php

Tags: php, arrays, laravel, eloquent

How can I get the array from a object? I'm trying to get to the empty array so that I can validate on it's empty state.

```
$object = Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection Object;

print_r($object);

if(empty($object->array)){

}
```

output

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection Object
(
    [items:protected] => Array
        (
        )

)
```

Comment: you can typecast it, like (array)$array

Comment: @melkawakibi look here https://stackoverflow.com/a/4345609/2520628

Comment: I change the code, now it's an Eloquent Object which has an Array inside

Comment: Have you tried the different ways described by Gary Green here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563166/eloquent-collection-counting-and-detect-empty ?

Comment: @melkawakibi - It's a ___protected___ property of the object.... that means it isn't directly accessible from outside the object.... Why don't you just use the object methods to access the data, rather than trying to break OOP

Comment: I just figured that out. It's of the type Collection which I didn't notice. Using the method Collection::isNotEmpty() is the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The object is of the type Eloquent\Collection which means that it has access to a set of methods.

[Eloquent\Collection | available methods](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-collections#available-methods)

Collection provides a set of methods to validate the state of an array inside the Object. Two of which are interesting in the case described by me (OP):

- IsEmpty
- IsNotEmpty

Implementation

```
$website = $this->websitedb->findOneByUrl($this->url);

if($website->isNotEmpty()){

    $uniqueId = rand() . $website[0]->id;

    //save scan to database
    $this->scan = $this->scandb->create($website[0]->id, $uniqueId);

    $this->scandb->createModule($this->scan->id, $options);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
if ($object->array === array()) {
    echo 'this is explicitly an empty array!';
}
```

Comment: It gives this error, Property [array] does not exist on this collection instance.