# Trying to get property of non-object error, count always return 1 even no empty array

Tags: laravel

I am displaying my data using datatable, if empty array then datatable will not be shown.

I tried

```
@if(count($results) > 0)
    //data show
@foreach($results as $r)
    <p>{{$r->name}}</p>
@endfor
@else
    No result found.
@endif
    //
    // $results is an array
```

This will return error if empty $result. How can i make it if $result is empty then show the custom message and not to display DataTable.

Comment: Show the controller code how you get result value?

Comment: @ChoncholMahmud i am select raw query DB::select($query);

Comment: This answer must solve your problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563166/eloquent-collection-counting-and-detect-empty?answertab=oldest#tab-top

Comment: what version of laravel btw?

Comment: @lagbox version 5.3.3

Comment: It is trying to get the property of an object($r->name) and states that $r is not an object..dd($r) to see if it is actually an object

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
@if(isset($results) && !empty($results))

    <?php
      print('<pre style="color:red;">');
    print_r($results);
    print('</pre>');


    ?>

  @foreach($results as $r)
   <p>{{$r->name}}</p>
  @endforeach
@else
  No result found.
@endif
```

Comment: Still same, it will go into first condiiton instead of  no result found which caused error.

Comment: please check my updated answer and please display result set of $results variable

Comment: Please remove exit line and check and i also remove exit(); line from my code

Comment: what do you mean by remove exit(); line?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159869/discussion-between-addweb-solution-pvt-ltd-and-zidance).

Answer (score 0):

Use `isEmpty()` to check object `empty` or not-

`@if (!$result->isEmpty())`

Comment: can you update your question with controller codes??

Answer (score 0):

We do have a shorthand in blade for the foreach/empty scenarios.

```
@forelse ($results as $r)
    <p>{{ $r->name }}</p>
@empty
    No result found
@endforelse
```

From the code you have and the comment you have of how you get `$results`, `$results` should be an array of `stdClass` objects, which means that error should not be happening. Since the code you have is limited, I can't be sure the error is coming from that code at all.

My guess is that `$results` isn't an array but is an object. `count(new stdClass) === 1` `count(new App\User) === 1`, etc ...

Comment: $results = DB::select($query);
$query = "select * from table..." i pass the $results to blade.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe is safer to check at the controller level and return 0 if $result is NULL

After you get the collection just check this:

```
$result = $result ? $result : 0
```

And return $result.

Answer (score 0):

You are ending the `foreach` loop with `endfor`. It should be ended with `endforeach`.

If this do not fix your error then please update your question with your controller code. Is your results variable a collection object?

Comment: Just mistype. The controller just $query = "select * from products" $results = DB::select($query); and then pass to blade only.

Comment: You can not directly pass the query in the select. Either you use DB::raw or try this 
$results = DB::table('products')->all();

Comment: i passed $results...not the $query to blade

Comment: Yes, I understand that. Please look at this. https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queries#raw-expressions

You can not pass complete query directly in select statement instead you need to use DB::raw... else use this query $results = DB::table('products')->get(); and pass $results in blade

Comment: Ikr. But i don't think this will caused the if-else statement to work? It will also facing the problem i mentioned. In my case, I able to display everything fine while there's data. I just want to catch when there's no record then run into else statement to show no result found.

Comment: What do you get if you just write {{$results}} in blade?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/159873/discussion-between-ashish-and-zidance).