# Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::isEmpty on eager loading laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.5

I have a `Cart` model like this :

```
class Cart extends Model
    {
        protected $table = 'cart';

        protected $fillable = ['user_id', 'delivery_method'];

        public function products ()
        {
            return $this->belongsToMany(Product::class, 'cart_products', 'cart_id', 'product_id')->withPivot('quantity');
        }

    }
```

And **cart** table columns are :

```
id
user_id
delivery_method
created_at
updated_at
```

And there is a pivot table named `cart_products` to relate `Card` model to a `Product` Model.

Suppose I have an specific `$user_id` variable. now I want Cart with that user_id with their products. for that I wrote this :

```
$cartWithProducts = Cart::with('products')->where(['user_id' => $user_id])->first();

if (!$cartWithProducts->isEmpty()) {
//Some codes come here
}
```

But after run, I got this error :

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::isEmpty() {"exception":"[object] (BadMethodCallException(code: 0): Call to undefined method Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder::isEmpty() at D:\\wamp\\www\\barlly\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder.php:2461
```

I do not want to use **lazy loading** approach beacause **n query** problem. what is solution in this case?

**Also each User can have only one Cart in time.**

Comment: When you call `first()`, it returns a single object or null. So, you are trying to call `isEmpty()`, which is a `Collection` method, on a single object.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

you can just call

```
if ($cartWithProducts) {
//Some codes come here
}
```

Have a read over this  [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563166/eloquent-collection-counting-and-detect-empty)

Comment: I tired that, But if block does not run while I have a Card this that conditions in database.

Comment: Oops, I forgot to remove `!`

Comment: use ->get() instead of ->first() in your query

Comment: But in this case it return an array of  cart, right?. but I only save one cart for each `user_id` and now I want to select that one only

Answer (score 3):

Expecting your can have multiple carts for specified users and you may proceed more than one I would recommend to do something like this:

```
$cartWithProducts = Cart::whereUserId($user_id)->with('products')->get();

if ($cartWithProducts->isNotEmpty()) {
    //Some codes come here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`first()` returns `null` if there is no Cart for the user, so if you want to check **if it's empty**, you can use `is_null()` or `empty()` instead of `if (!$cartWithProducts)` to keep is readable:

```
if (is_null($cartWithProducts))
```