# Finding out if a table is empty in laravel

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to find out if my table is empty but I get this error

> Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\isEmpty()

I did check the question that had a similar title to mine but that didn't have what I needed.

Here is my code

```
$orders = Order::all();

if(isEmpty($orders))
{
    echo "Im empty";
    die();
 }else{
    echo "im not empty";
     die();
 }
```

Comment: try this `if($orders->isEmpty())` am sure it will work.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563166/eloquent-collection-counting-and-detect-empty

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Eloquent Collection: Counting and Detect Empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563166/eloquent-collection-counting-and-detect-empty)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to check an array, use `empty($orders)`, for a Laravel Collection you can use `$orders->isEmpty()`

Currently you're calling a function `isEmpty()`, which doesn't exist.

Try this:

```
$orders = Order::all();

if($orders->isEmpty())
{
    echo "Im empty";
    die();
 }else{
    echo "im not empty";
     die();
 }
```

Comment: This might give issues when you have like a lot of records in that table without a limiter, paging or anything. I would not recommend using this method. Say you have 2000 records. That's 2000 records that get loaded into ram, then hydrated into models, filling up your ram, snooping at CPU capacity.  An `::exists()` or `count()` would be more at place, than this overly heavy operation.

Answer (score 8):

You should use `Model::exists()`. It returns true/false and runs a `select count(*) from table where` query under the hood.

```
if (Order::exists()) {
    echo "im not empty";
    die();
} else {
    echo "Im empty";
    die();
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Ok since all of the answers in here are not `good/optimized` here is the fastest way to check whether a table has `any rows/table is not empty`

```php
$order = Order::first();
if(is_null($order)) {
    // Table is empty.
}else {
    // Table is not empty.
}
```

`Order::all()` and `Order::count()` is bad because your table may have millions of records in it and when you get all rows you may get memory exception or even system hanging

Answer (score 3):

You can call eloquent `count` function to get count and then check if count is equal to zero.

```
$products = Order::count(); //returns products count
if($products == 0){
    //products table is empty
}
```

or

```
if($collection->isEmpty()){
//products table is empty.
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The optimal and fastest way to check if a table is empty is by:

```
//When using eloquent
if(empty(Order::count())){
   // Do something here
}
```

Or

```
//When using query builder
if(empty(DB::table('orders')->count())){
   // Do something here
}
```

Internally these will count total number of rows on the database itself and it will generate the following query.

```
select count(*) as aggregate from `orders`
```

Answer (score -1):

According to  Laravel [Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/collections#method-isempty) states you can use this way:

```
$orders = Order::all();
if($orders->isEmpty())
{   
  echo "Im empty";
} else {
  echo "Im not empty";
}
```