# if and else condition not working in laravel for the array of data

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

else condition, sorry no items in your cart not printing when the cart is empty

```
@if($datas)
   @foreach($datas as $data)
   <h5>This is product</h5>
    @endforeach
@else
        <h5>Sorry no items in your cart</h5>    // Not printing when cart is empty  
@endif
```

Comment: i guess you receive an array of objects in `datas`, right? have you tried to `count` it? and can you var_dump the initial entry of the `datas` before the `if` statement

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be you are getting `$datas` as an empty collection.

If you are getting a **collection** in `$datas` from Eloquent model then you can check it with `isNotEmpty` as below

```
@if($datas->isNotEmpty())
    @foreach($datas as $data)
        <h5>This is product</h5>
    @endforeach
@else
    // $data is empty
@endif
```

for more see [documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/collections#method-isnotempty)

or you can simply check it by `empty()` **(for arrays)** method as below

```
@if(!empty($datas))
    @foreach($datas as $data)
        <h5>This is product</h5>
    @endforeach
@else
    // $data is empty
@endif
```

Answer (score 1):

if its **array** data then use **empty()**

```
@if(!empty($datas))
@else
@endif
```

or other way use **count()**

```
@if(count($datas) > 0)
@else
@endif
```

or if its **collection** then use **isEmpty()**

```
@if(!$datas->isEmpty())
@else
@endif
```

Answer (score 1):

check the array is empty or not with empty() function

```
@if(!empty($datas))
    @foreach($datas as $data)
        <h5>This is product</h5>
    @endforeach
@else
    //do 
@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

I can see answers almost. But let me explain bit more.I can see that you are checking `$datas` is empty or not. If you use helper function `dd()` to dump `$datas` values you can see that it always return a Collection from `Illuminate\Support\Collection`. So even `$datas` is empty it gives a empty Collection. You can test this by your self like below in your controller

```
if($datas) {
   dd($datas);
}else{
   dd('empty');
}
```

This will always show the empty Collection. So just using `if` condition you cann't check a collection is empty. Instead of `if` you can check a collection with below methods.

1. `collect([])->isEmpty();`

   ```
   @if ($datas->isEmpty())

   @endif
   ```
2. `collect([])->isNotEmpty();`

   ```
   @if ($datas->isNotEmpty())

   @endif
   ```
3. `collect([])->first();`

   ```
   @if ($datas->first())

   @endif
   ```
4. `collect([])->count();`

   ```
   @if ($datas->count())

   @endif
   ```

If you check Laravel Collection documentation you can find more.

[Collections full documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/collections)

[Location above methods available](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/collections#method-isempty)

*Edit 01*
This answer directly answer your question. Please check

[Eloquent Collection: Counting and Detect Empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563166/eloquent-collection-counting-and-detect-empty)

Answer (score 0):

You can use laravel's forelse loop - https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/blade#loops

```
@forelse ($datas as $data)
    <h5>This is product</h5>
@empty
    <h5>Sorry no items in your cart</h5>
@endforelse
```