# because it shows Undefined offset: 0, seeder laravel?

Tags: laravel-5

I have the following for in which I create the records

```
foreach ($v as $k => $f){
            if($v[$k] !=  false && $f['zip_code'] !=''){
                $state = State::whereCode($f['code'])->get();
                var_dump($state[0]->id);
                  \App\Models\ZipCodes::create([
                    'uuid'  => Uuid::generate(4)->string,
                    'zip_code'  => $f['zip_code'],
                    'city'  => $f['city'],
                    'county'  => $f['county'],
                    'state_id'  => $state[0]->id,
                ]); 
            }
        }
```

I have noticed that the error appears in the field `'state_id' => $ state [0] -> id`
since if I comment and delete it from the table it doesn't give me the error.

In fact if I just leave

```
foreach ($v as $k => $f){
            if($v[$k] !=  false && $f['zip_code'] !=''){
                $state = State::whereCode($f['code'])->get();
                var_dump($state[0]->id);
            }
}
```

The same generates the error.

Comment: I think this query `$state = State::whereCode($f['code'])->get();` it's returnig an empty collection.

Comment: that's the problem, it's empty. How can I add that if it comes empty, keep empty

Comment: Do you mean on `'state_id'  => $state[0]->id,` when you create the ZipCodes? It's a nullable field?

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, you are asking how to check if your collection is empty or not?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Eloquent Collection: Counting and Detect Empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20563166/eloquent-collection-counting-and-detect-empty)